# Problem with Android Gradle, it gives the error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to build a project, but the error

> "- Problem: In version catalog libs, you can only import a single
> external catalog in a given catalog definition."

I checked the toml file, here it is:

```
    [versions]
    
    # Plugins
    android-gradle-plugin = "7.0.0"
    spotless-plugin-gradle = "5.12.5"
    
    # Kotlin
    kotlin = "1.5.21"
    ktlint = "0.41.0"
    
    # AndroidX
    androidx-core-ktx = "1.5.0"
    androidx-appcompat = "1.3.0"
    
    # UI
    material = "1.3.0"
    
    # Hilt DI
    hilt = "2.36"
    
    # JVM Unit Tests
    junit = "4.13.2"
    
    # Instrumentation Tests
    androidx-junit = "1.1.2"
    androidx-espresso-core = "3.3.0"
    
    
    [libraries]
    
    # Plugins
    spotless-plugin-gradle = { module = "com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle", version.ref = "spotless-plugin-gradle" }
    android-gradle-plugin = { module = "com.android.tools.build:gradle", version.ref = "android-gradle-plugin" }
    kotlin-gradle-plugin = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "kotlin" }
    
    # Kotlin
    kotlin-stdlib = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib", version.ref = "kotlin" }
    
    # AndroidX
    androidx-core-ktx = { module = "androidx.core:core-ktx", version.ref = "androidx-core-ktx" }
    androidx-appcompat = { module = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat", version.ref = "androidx-appcompat" }
    
    # UI
    material = { module = "com.google.android.material:material", version.ref = "material" }
    
    # Hilt DI
    hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
    hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }
    
    # Hilt DI - JVM / Instrumentation Tests
    hilt-testing = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing", version.ref = "hilt" }
    
    # JVM Unit Tests
    junit = { module = "junit:junit", version.ref = "junit" }
    
    # Instrumentation Tests
    androidx-junit = { module = "androidx.test.ext:junit", version.ref = "androidx-junit" }
    androidx-espresso-core = { module = "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core", version.ref = "androidx-espresso-core" }

[plugins]

    # Plugins
    hilt-gradle-plugin = { id = "dagger.hilt.android.plugin", version.ref = "hilt" }
    spotless-plugin-gradle = { id = "com.diffplug.spotless", version.ref = "spotless-plugin-gradle" }
    kotlin-gradle-plugin = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "kotlin" }
    android-gradle-plugin = { id = "com.android.tools.build:gradle", version.ref = "android-gradle-plugin"}
```

There seem to be no errors here

Here is the file settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = "IME"
include ':app'
```

There is no second .toml file in the project.

I also did clearing the Gradle cache and rebooting.

Tell me, please, what is the problem?

UPD:
A new problem has appeared
Gradle sees everything, from `classpath` you can go to `[plugins]`, but the following error appears:

```
> A problem occurred configuring root project 'IME'.
> > Could not determine the dependencies of null.
>    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>       > Cannot convert the provided notation to an object of type Dependency: dagger.hilt.android.plugin:2.36.
>         The following types/formats are supported:
>           - String or CharSequence values, for example 'org.gradle:gradle-core:1.0'.
>           - Maps, for example [group: 'org.gradle', name: 'gradle-core', version: '1.0'].
>           - FileCollections, for example files('some.jar', 'someOther.jar').
>           - Projects, for example project(':some:project:path').
>           - ClassPathNotation, for example gradleApi().
```

I can’t understand what kind of error this is, there’s nothing special on the Internet (or I’m not looking well), chatGPT gives the same advice
that doesn’t work.
Please tell me what the error is and how to fix it.
I add additional code, in case something is wrong there:

app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version libs.versions.android.gradle.plugin
    id 'kotlin-android' version libs.versions.kotlin
    id 'kotlin-kapt' version libs.versions.kotlin
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin' version libs.versions.hilt
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.litekite.ime"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += "src/main/kotlin"
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
        warningsAsErrors true
        enable "Interoperability"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

    }
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation(libs.kotlin.stdlib)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)

    // Hilt
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)

    // Hilt - Instrumentation test helpers
    androidTestImplementation(libs.hilt.testing)
    kaptAndroidTest(libs.hilt.compiler)

    // Hilt - Local unit test helpers
    testImplementation(libs.hilt.testing)
    kaptTest(libs.hilt.compiler)

    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
      
        classpath(libs.plugins.hilt.gradle.plugin)
        classpath(libs.plugins.kotlin.gradle.plugin)
        classpath(libs.plugins.spotless.plugin.gradle)

    }
}

apply plugin: "com.diffplug.spotless"
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

spotless {
    ratchetFrom 'origin/main'
    format 'misc', {
        target '**/*.gradle', '**/*.md', '**/.gitignore'
        trimTrailingWhitespace()
        indentWithSpaces()
        endWithNewline()
    }
    format 'xml', {
        target '**/*.xml'
        trimTrailingWhitespace()
        indentWithSpaces()
        endWithNewline()
    }
    kotlin {
        target '**/src/**/*.kt'
        ktlint(libs.versions.ktlint.get())
        licenseHeaderFile rootProject.file('spotless/copyright.kt')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle defines a dependency on a .toml version catalog if it's present.

> By default, the libs.versions.toml file will be an input to the libs catalog

So there is no need to specify version catalog in settings.gradle.kts. Try removing version catalog specification and resync the project. Your `settings.gradle.kts` file should be updated as below:

```
rootProject.name = "IME"
include ':app'

enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
```

There is also no point in specifying `enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")` as version catalogs have been promoted to stable in 7.4 and completely [removed](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/29bbb70e78e70d235053ca5e4a38b0f9bcfe4cce) preview option in 8.0

Comment: I used 7.2, updated to 8.0
Another error appeared:
"On plugin declaration 'hilt-gradle-plugin' expected to find any of 'id' or 'version' but found unexpected key 'module'"

Comment: Make sure your other dependencies are compatible with Gradle 8.0
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Comment: Your advice helped a little, but another error appeared.
I added the UPD item to the question, please look and if you know, help

Comment: Your build files combine legacy approach of applying plugins with the new plugins block. Try to update your root-level build.gradle file to use plugins block and declare plugins with applying them and get rid of classpath dependencies and legacy apply. Then apply those same plugins from your app-level build.gradle file (you won't have to specify version). 
To check the issue is what I think it is try swapping dependencies in buildscript. If the issues changes from hilt to kotlin it's likely I am right

Answer (score 1):

Use `id` instead of `module` for plugin definitions.

```
[plugins]
hilt-gradle-plugin = { id = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "hilt" }
```

App-level `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt.gradle.plugin)
}
```

Top level `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
   alias(libs.plugins.hilt.gradle.plugin) apply false
}
```

It is all described here: [Migrate plugins](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs#migrate-plugins), so if you have any further questions, check it out.

Comment: It didn’t help, for some reason there was a problem with the hilt-gradle-plugin alias when processing the Gradle configuration file.
Error: - Problem: In version catalog libs, alias 'hilt-gradle-plugin' is not a valid alias.

Comment: Well, that is a different error. Aliases are divided with dots, not hyphens, so in your `build.gradle.kts` it should be `alias(libs.plugins.hilt.gradle.plugin)` @VladTkachev

Comment: I did as you said, but new errors appeared
I added the UPD item to the question, please look and if you know, help
I tried it myself, but I couldn’t really find anything to solve this problem.